# Removing zero values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello I am working with javascript at the moment, and I wanting to remove zero values from an array, the array looks like this,

```
0 : Object  
     color : "#24a7e1",
     data  : Array[119],
     name  : "Active
     status : 2
1 : Object
     color : "#26a727",
     data  : Array[119],
     name  : Completed,
     status: 4
```

This array can have any number of objects, what I need to do is loop through array, descend into each data attributes and remove from that array any values that are 0.

I have made an attempt on a specific array with the object

```
for(var i=0; i<filteredValueData[0].data.length;i++ )
{ 
     if(filteredValueData[0].data[i] == 0)
         filteredValueData[0].data[i].splice(i,1); 
}
```

I get the error,

> filteredValueData[0].data[i].splice is not a function

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong, the object can have anywhere from 0 arrays to 5 arrays in it

Comment: Once you fix that error you might want to consider that your loop will skip the element after each removed element. (I suggest fixing it by looping backwards.)

Comment: Do you want remove element with index 0 or all elements where values are 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  filteredValueData[0].data[i].splice(i,1);
```

This means that you try to run code on i element in array. If i understood you correctly then i would do this like that

```
for(var i=0; i<filteredValueData.length;i++ )
{ 
    filteredValueData[i].data = filteredValueData[i].data.filter(function(item){return item !== 0})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of issues in it, try this updated one

```
for(var i=0; i<filteredValueData[0].data.length;i++ )
{ 
     if(filteredValueData[0].data[i] == 0)
     {
         filteredValueData[0].data.splice(i,1);  //data[i] is replaced with data
         i--; //reduce the i counter;
     }
}
```

check this simple example

```
var a = [1,2,3,0,2,1,0,2,3];
for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++ )
{ 
     if(a[i] == 0)
     {
         a.splice(i,1);  //data[i] is replaced with data
         i--; //reduce the i counter;
     }
} 
console.log(a);//[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```